# Removing brackets around a string and placing contents into new object

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, angular-services, angular-filters

I have an angular service which returns an array with a number of objects inside.

**$scope.data:**

```
[
    {
        date: "03/12/2014",
        name: "mr blue",
        title: "math teacher (Germany)"
    },
    {
        date: "04/02/2015",
        name: "mrs yellow",
        title: "chemistry teacher (Spain)"
    },
]
```

You can see from the title field it contains a title and a location. How can i separate the title and location? Whilst removing the brackets too?

**Service:**

```
$scope.loadFeed=function(e){        
    myService.parseFeed(url).then(function(res) {
        $scope.data = res.data.responseData.feed.entries;
    });
}
```

What i have tried is:

```
$scope.loadFeed=function(e){        
    myService.parseFeed(url).then(function(res) {
        $scope.data = res.data.responseData.feed.entries;

        var strWithoutBracket = $scope.data[0].title.replace(/\(.*?\)/g,'');
        console.log(strWithoutBracket);

        $scope.location = strWithoutBracket;

    });
}
```

However `console.log(strWithoutBracket);` is displaying as:

```
chemistry teacher
```

Essentially what i am after is a `$scope.title` without the location. And `$scope.location` without the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete solution for title and location :

```
var str = "chemistry teacher (Spain)";

var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
var matches = regExp.exec(str);

var title = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('('));
var location = matches[1];

console.log('title : ' + title);
console.log('location : ' + location);
```

[JSBin here](http://jsbin.com/qaluwutuda/1/)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$scope.data = [
    {
        date: "03/12/2014",
        name: "mr blue",
        title: "math teacher (Germany)"
    },
    {
        date: "04/02/2015",
        name: "mrs yellow",
        title: "chemistry teacher (Spain)"
    },
];

angular.forEach($scope.data, function(item){
    var values = /(.*)\s+\((.+)\)\s*$/.exec(item.title||"") || [];
    item.title = values[1];
    item.location = values[2];
});

console.log($scope.data);
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/1dW1lYLY2PzVwszs5XNo?p=preview)**

Answer (score 2):

You are already getting chemistry teacher, which you should set to title instead of location.

Here is what you can do:

```
var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
$scope.location = regExp.exec($scope.data[0].title);

$scope.data[0].title = $scope.data[0].title.replace(/\(.*?\)/g,'');
```

Should have both your title and location updated as required.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can try. In the regex below I assumed that at least one whitespace character between title and location in brackets.

```
var locationRegex = /\s+\(([a-zA-Z]*)\)*/;
var strWithoutBracket = $scope.data[0].title.replace(locationRegex,'');
var location = $scope.data[0].title.match(locationRegex)[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use code like this:

```js
var str = "math teacher (Germany)";
var m = str.match(/(.*) *\((.*)\)/);
var obj = {
  title: m[1],
  location: m[2]
};
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var strWithoutBracket = $scope.data[0].title.replace(/([()])+/g,'');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
var strWithoutBracket = $scope.data[0].title.split((/\(([^}]+)\)/)[1]));
console.log(strWithoutBracket);
```